# How to correctly create signed certificates for registry and device in Google IoT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssl, certificate, google-cloud-iot

I have a project based on Google Cloud Platform which involves adding Raspberry Pi devices to **Google IoT** registry. What I need to do is to generate signed certificates both for registry and for devices in order to ensure that fraudulent devices are not registered.

I already tried generating signed X.509 certificates like this:

```
   openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt
```

```
   openssl genrsa -out device.key 2048
```

```
   openssl req -new -days 365 -key device.key -out device.csr
```

```
   openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in device.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out device.crt
```

Notice that when promtped I put additional *subj* information like name, country, email, organisation which according to [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591414/digitally-signing-a-device-public-key-with-ca-certificate) should make it work.

After invoking those commands I end up with following files:

```
ca.crt     ca.key     ca.srl     device.crt device.csr device.key
```

So what I would do is to add *ca.crt* as **registry certificate** and then when I try to upload *device.crt* as **device certificate** (type RS256_X509) I get an error `Certificate is not supported by Cloud IoT`

What could I be doing wrong? I want to make sure that I create correct certificates and link them to registry and device.

Comment: Have a look at this article I wrote. It was to use Onion's Omega devices but the principles should be the same for your Pi. https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-iot-core-golang-b130f65951ba

Comment: I cannot register a device with default subj information, but with `Common Name` set to unused when running `openssl req -new -days 365 -key device.key -out device.csr` and leaving everything else as default, I was able to register a device with your exact same commands. Could you provide more info as to which additional subj information you used?